# How to delete element from list

Tags: haskell

i'm trying to learn haskell. i want to delete an element from list.

This is my code :

```
import Data.List
data IllegalMove = IllegalMove deriving (Show, Eq)
data Suit = Clubs | Diamonds | Hearts | Spades deriving (Show, Eq)
data Rank = Jack | Queen | King | Ace | Num Int deriving (Show, Eq)
type Card = (Suit, Rank)
removeCard :: [Card] -> Card -> Either IllegalMove [Card]
removeCard [] card = Left IllegalMove
removeCard [cards] card 
      | card `elem` [cards] = Right (delete card [cards])
      | otherwise = Left IllegalMove
```

so when i try to compile this example i got an error :

```
*Main> removeCard [(Clubs,King),(Diamonds,Queen)] (Clubs,Queen )
*** Exception: Assignment13.hs:(7,1)-(10,38): Non-exhaustive patterns in function removeCard
```

Comment: All you have to do is replace all instances of `[cards]` with simply `cards`. Then you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Import `Data.List`. And use [Hoogle](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle?q=delete&env=ghc-7.8-stable-14.09).